# Loop Velocity.js sequence of custom effects

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I am using the Velocity UI library for text animation. I have registered two effects (In & Out, thus it handles the display property), and they are running in a sequence. How can I loop the sequence? I tried to trigger it as an option at the last in the sequence, but it did not work (as the running of the sequence is not a function).

I went through the answers here on Stack Overflow and on Github, but I could not figure out an answer. Please give me a suggestion what would be a good way to put it on an infinite loop. Thank you!

```
$.Velocity.RegisterUI("mythingIn", {
    calls: [ 
         [{ color: "#fff", opacity: 1 }, 0.5],
         [{ color: "#ffac00" }, 0.5]
    ]
});

$.Velocity.RegisterUI("mythingOut", {
    calls: [ 
        [{ opacity: 0 }] 
    ]
});

var a1wordflow1 = [
    { e: $('.a1w-1-1'), p: ("mythingIn"), o: { stagger: 70, duration: Math.random()*6000+14000 } },
    { e: $('.a1w-1-1'), p: ("mythingOut"), o: { stagger: 70, duration: 800 } },
    { e: $('.a1w-1-2'), p: ("mythingIn"), o: { stagger: 70, duration: Math.random()*6000+14000 } },
    { e: $('.a1w-1-2'), p: ("mythingOut"), o: { stagger: 70, duration: 800 } },
];

$.Velocity.RunSequence(a1wordflow1);
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a Codepen or similar that we can look at to see the result of your code and be able to help you run the loop ?

Comment: It is running here on a test page, with the full data: [link](http://www.viragcukor.hu/landing-v1.php). I set up a Codepen as well soon.

Comment: Great, please comment when you have setup the working Codepen.

Comment: Thanks! https://codepen.io/helgav/pen/rGpWxo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to calculate the total time of your sequence in advance, then call your sequence inside a `setInterval` call.

```
$.Velocity.RegisterUI("mythingIn", {
    // ...
});

$.Velocity.RegisterUI("mythingOut", {
    // ...
});

const rand = Math.random()*6000+14000;

var a1wordflow1 = [
    { e: $('.a1w-1-1'), p: ("mythingIn"), o: { stagger: 70, duration:  rand } } ,
    { e: $('.a1w-1-1'), p: ("mythingOut"), o: { stagger: 70, duration: 800 } },
    { e: $('.a1w-1-2'), p: ("mythingIn"), o: { stagger: 70, duration: rand } },
    { e: $('.a1w-1-2'), p: ("mythingOut"), o: { stagger: 70, duration: 800 } },
];

let totalTime = 2 * rand + 1600 + maybeSomeOtherTime;

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    $.Velocity.RunSequence(a1wordflow1);
}, totalTime);
```

If you some time later decide to stop the loop, you need to add the following to your code to stop the loop :

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well. I wanted to have different randoms for all elements, but that is not a problem, i can generate and add it into total time. Also, the stagger needs extra time as well.   Many thanks for your help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: Sure, my pleasure, glad I could help.

Comment: Just for the future reference: in the meantime i also have figured out that the animation is already randomised by the stagger, as the animated text length is different. All i had to do is set the first element's duration differently. Many, many thanks!